# Set column names with Pandas using a file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import, names

I have such instructions:
Import the dataset from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/ auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data-original with Pandas. Add columns name using the name parameter of read_csv and consulting: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/ auto-mpg/auto-mpg.names. You can check the impact of using sep=r"\s+".

So I download the dataset and use sep=r"\s+":

```
data_auto = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data-original", comment="#", sep=r"\s+")
```

, but I have no idea how to set column names using this strange file with .names extension. Do you guys have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: You can look at the .names file with any text editor, it is just a plain text file with a description of the data. You can put all the attributes in a list and make them the new column names: `data_auto.columns = ["mpg", "cylinders", "displacement", "horsepower", "weight", "acceleration", "model year", "orgin", "car name"]`

Comment: Thank you! for some reason I wasn't able to open the file

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition by using [**`pandas.read_fwf`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

# --- Retrieving the columns names

cols_df = pd.read_fwf("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.names", header=None)
cols_df.loc[cols_df[1] == 'Attribute Information:', 0] = 'Attribute Information'
cols_df = cols_df.ffill()
cols_df.iloc[:,0] == 'Attribute Information'
cols_df['column_name'] = cols_df[1].str.split(r'\s* \s*|\s*:\s*').str[1]
cols_df = cols_df[cols_df[0] == 'Attribute Information']
cols_names = cols_df['column_name'].tolist()[1:]

# --- Creating the AUTO dataframe

data_auto = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data-original", header=None, comment="#", sep=r"\s+", names=cols_names)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(data_auto.head())

    mpg  cylinders  displacement  horsepower  weight  acceleration  model  origin                        car
0  18.0        8.0         307.0       130.0  3504.0          12.0   70.0     1.0  chevrolet chevelle malibu
1  15.0        8.0         350.0       165.0  3693.0          11.5   70.0     1.0          buick skylark 320
2  18.0        8.0         318.0       150.0  3436.0          11.0   70.0     1.0         plymouth satellite
3  16.0        8.0         304.0       150.0  3433.0          12.0   70.0     1.0              amc rebel sst
4  17.0        8.0         302.0       140.0  3449.0          10.5   70.0     1.0                ford torino
```